# Bulk insert when using IDENTITY

Tags: sql-server

This is my table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE emp
   (empid INT IDENTITY(101, 1),
    empname VARCHAR(20),
    salary DECIMAL(10,2),
    Created_date DATETIME DEFAULT(GETDATE())
   );
```

Now I have records like

```
'Ramesh',10000
'Arun',20000
```

in a `.txt` file.

I need to bulk insert those records into the table. Please guide me to write the bulk insert query.

Comment: This isn't a lot to go off. Could you rewrite your question with more details, please?

Comment: What did you try and what didn't work?

Comment: You must at least have started have started a query and got an error message...

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you first need a **staging** table that has a structure that **exactly matches** your `.txt` file:

```
CREATE TABLE emp_staging
   (empname VARCHAR(20),
    salary DECIMAL(10,2)
   );
```

Then, BULK INSERT the data from the `.txt` file into your staging table and check:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.emp_staging
   FROM 'd:\temp\emps.txt'
   WITH 
      (
         FIELDTERMINATOR =',',
         ROWTERMINATOR ='\n'
      );

SELECT * FROM dbo.emp_staging
```

Once that's done - now you can insert the data from the staging table into the actual table using `INSERT .. SELECT ...`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.emp
        ( empname, salary )
    SELECT empname, salary
    FROM dbo.emp_staging

SELECT * FROM dbo.emp
```